Anaconda fails to install on Macbook
I'm a beginner level working on a Data Analytics course that requires to install Anaconda. I have MacBook (Sonoma OS) and keep running into different issues during the installation. When I do the graphical installer the download stops and says "the installation failed and to contact the software manufacture" then when I do the command line download the installation will stop and says ‘bad cpu in executable.’
I downloaded the latest version of the installer file from the Anaconda website and tried installing using the command line.
I have switched to zsh shell as someone recommended and that did not help. Does anyone know how I can resolve it?

as I know Anaconda uses precompiled modules - to make life simpler. But it seems they are precompiled for different CPU. You may need to get source code and compile it on your own - but I don't know if Anaconda gives source code, and it may need to install compilers for C, C++ and maybe even Fortran. OR maybe you should use standard Python and install all modules with pip without using Anaconda

Try installing Rosetta as per this Miniconda question

If the problem persists, could you please edit the question to include the full CPU model for your computer and the full error message (delimited by back-ticks so that it can be seen clearly).

Make sure that you use the 64-bit (M1) installer of anaconda
